# replacement for is in jqlite in angular application

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqlite

I want to write the following expression with jqlite instead of jQuery:

```
element.is (':visible')
```

In jqlite there is no "is" function.

Comment: Presuming you are showing/hiding the element - how are you doing this?

Comment: with `ng-show` / `ng-hide` on parent elements